# Inserting a sparse vector into a sparse matrix

Tags: haskell, sparse-matrix, matrix-multiplication, cabal, sparse-vector

I want to set the column of a sparse matrix using a sparse matrix and a sparse vector. Tried to check the relevant documents but I got stuck on this part. Is this possible?
If it helps I'm building with cabal. I'm ok with changing/adding libraries as long as they can handle sparse matrices and vectors combined.

```
import Data.Sparse.SpMatrix
import Data.Sparse.SpVector 
import Numeric.LinearAlgebra.Sparse

main :: IO ()
main = do
let m1 = fromListSM (3,3) 
        [(0,0,1)
        ,(1,1,2)
        ,(2,2,3)
        ] :: SpMatrix Double
    let v = fromListSV 3 [(0,1),(1,4),(2,9)] :: SpVector Double
    let m2 = ...
```

How can I define `m2` here for this to work? It should be just like `m1`, but with the middle column exchanged for `v`.

In this example the expected outcome for `m2` is

```
1 1 _
_ 4 _ 
_ 9 3
```

Comment: Which package(s) are you using?

Comment: My .cabal contains:
build depends: base, hmatrix, hmatrix-gsl, sparse-linear-algebra, prettyprinter, vector
I'm ok with removing/adding to make it work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was missing a related module which contained what I wanted.

```
import Data.Sparse.Common
```

Now all I needed was to define `m2` as this:

```
let m2 = insertCol m1 v 1
```

Comment: Are you sure this does what you want? The question says you want to "set" a column, which sounds to me like it means "replace" or "overwrite": set a column of the matrix, ignoring what was there before. But my reading of `insertCol` is that it *adds* elements to a column. It will overwrite any conflicts, but if an entrt is present in the original matrixs' column and not present in the replacement vector, it stays in the result vector.

Comment: @amalloy I tried to catch what you mean but it doesn't seem like it adds, but replaces: if it were to add, the middle, which is 4 here, would be 2 + 4 = 6.
Oh wait I see what you mean. Yes, if for example the third index of the vector is empty ( _ ) and that the third row in the matrix (in the targeted column) isn't empty the value of the matrix will be kept. For me this is still okay as in my case the column will be empty.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see an obviously great way to do this operation using the matrix-based APIs in `sparse-linear-algebra`. However, the constructors are exported, and you can clearly see an [`SpMatrix`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/sparse-linear-algebra-0.3.1/docs/Data-Sparse-SpMatrix.html#v:sizeStrSM) is just an `IntMap (IntMap a)` with a dimension, and an [`SpVector`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/sparse-linear-algebra-0.3.1/docs/Data-Sparse-SpVector.html#t:SpVector) is just an `IntMap a` with a dimension. So if you can't find any cleverer approach, you can just reach inside and [`insert`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.7/docs/Data-IntMap-Strict.html#v:insert) the row you want into the underlying map.

Comment: The insert you linked only works for single elements, right? I have found the somewhat equivalent [insertSpMatrix](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/sparse-linear-algebra-0.3.1/docs/Data-Sparse-SpMatrix.html#g:8)
But I was wondering if there was something like InsertSpMatrix for an entire row or column

Comment: @Pompan Ah, I somehow missed that you wanted to edit a column. My suggestion would work to replace a row.